# Expo how to get autogenerated ios certificates?

Tags: ios, certificate, command-line-interface, expo

I did use `expo build:ios`. Then let expo to handle certificates creation. So it created three things:

- Distribution certificate
- APNS certificate
- Provision profile

I need distribution certificate with private key for p12. From apple.developer i can download only open key. Where expo storing private cert and how to get it (add to keychain)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expo fetch:ios:certs
```

Above command would save generated certificates under the project root.

You can check more detail by `expo --help`.